# Swift ios Kanna data returning empty first time in viewDidLoad

Tags: arrays, swift, kanna

I am trying to load data from an API into my TableViewController but the first time it loads the data returns empty. I can't build a table because the data is empty.

```
import UIKit
import Kanna

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var country = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gets()
    print(country)// is empty view controller.
}
func gets(){

    let url = "https://site"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let URLTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL! as URL) {
        myData, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {return}
        let myHTML = String(data: myData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            if let doc = try? HTML(html: myHTML!, encoding: .utf8) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    for fdata in doc.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table[3]") {
                        let i = fdata.text!
                        self.country.append(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    URLTask.resume()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return country.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = country[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

I know that there are many similar problems. I tried different options but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Use the viewWillAppear (_animated: Bool) method that is called before the view appears on the screen.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    gets()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is coming from a network request, the table will always be empty initially. You could fetch the data from the previous view controller (displaying some kind of loading indicator) and wait to present this one until the fetch has completed.

Or, if you are just looking to reload your table when the data comes in, try adding  a `self.tableView.reloadData()` after the data has loaded:

```
...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for fdata in doc.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table[3]") {
            let i = fdata.text!
            self.country.append(i)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
...
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, what is the value of `self.country` after the for loop?